# List connectivity of points in discretized mesh

Tags: regions, mesh

I'm trying to automate the extraction of the points and a compatible connectivity list for meshes created using the `DiscretizeRegion` or similar method.

If I create a bounding polygon from a list of points (x,y,z) I could then start to create a discretized mesh using the `DiscretizeRegion` function.  Sample code I've been tinkering with below, using a `Disk[]` for illustration...

```
foo = DiscretizeRegion[Disk[], MaxCellMeasure -> 0.1]
```

[image]

And the points from the mesh I believe can be extracted using:

```
MeshCoordinates[foo]
```

In addition to the co-ordinates of the nodes I would also like to extract a list of connectivity that I can then take forward into my analysis.

For example, say that `MeshCoordinates[foo]` returns a list of co-ordinates in {x,y,z} format, say:

`{{x1,y1,z1},{x2,y2,z2},{x3,y3,z3}, etc}`

and if that first point is connected to the second and the third point (but the second and third points are not connected),  the list that I'm looking to create, that would define the connectivity would be:

`{{1,2},{1,3}}`

Ideally all of the perimeter nodes would be defined in sequential order, with the internal node numbering following on with the next node number in the sequence.  ie the perimeter nodes could be 1-10, with the first internal node being node number 11.

Comment: I don't have version 10 (or a computer, for that matter), but I believe the output of `DiscretizeRegion[]` should have a `GraphicsComplex[]` object in it somewhere. Can you check?

Comment: I'm not sure how I would check that in all honesty... I'll dig into it and see if I can work out how to check the output

Comment: What does `InputForm[foo]` give you?

Comment: MeshRegion[{{1., 0.}, {0.900968867902419, 0.4338837391175581}………
{Polygon[{{9, 10, 23}, {35, 8, 9}, {29, 20, 16}, …..
 Properties -> {{0, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14}} -> 
    MeshCellMarker -> {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, 
   {0, Default} -> MeshCellMarker -> 0, 
   {1, {42, 47, 10, 85, 78, 49, 5, 52, 1, 65, 18, 72, 63, 58}} -> 
    MeshCellMarker -> {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, 
   {1, Default} -> MeshCellMarker -> 0},

Comment: MeshCellMarker -> {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, 
   {1, Default} -> MeshCellMarker -> 0}, 
 Method -> {"EliminateUnusedCoordinates" -> True, 
   "DeleteDuplicateCoordinates" -> Automatic, "VertexAlias" -> Identity, 
   "CheckOrientation" -> True, "CoplanarityTolerance" -> Automatic, 
   "CheckIntersections" -> Automatic, "BoundaryNesting" -> Automatic, 
   "SeparateBoundaries" -> False, "PropagateMarkers" -> True, 
   "Hash" -> 7008025742547179298}]

Comment: I've hacked out some of the co-ordinates and shortened the list on the Polygon run to let the output fit...

Comment: The stuff within `Polygon[]` looks to be useful; you'll note that it has a list of triples, corresponding to the triangle whose vertices are indexed by the integers in the triple. You should now have something to start with.

Comment: I think you're right I could probably parse the list with some sorting and removal of duplicates, is there a way of extracting the output into a list?

Comment: `First[foo]` should yield the points; `Cases[foo, Polygon[p_] :> p, Infinity][[1]]` should give the polygon indices.

Comment: Doesn't quite extract them, I've manually copied them out and created the list with some Riffle and Partitioning... just need to automate the extraction of the Polygons now.... thanks for the help

Comment: Something like this? `test=ToString[InputForm[foo]];ToExpression[StringTake[test,StringPosition[test,"Polygon"][[1, 1]],   StringPosition[test, "Properties"][[1, 1]] - 4}]]`

Comment: Have a look at the documentation for [ToElementMesh](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/ref/ToElementMesh.html) and  [ElementMesh](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/ref/ElementMesh.html). Either use the `ElementIncidents` or the boundary or mesh element connectivity data structures. There is also a [Tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/ElementMeshCreation.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If we want all pairs of indices of vertices connected by a line segment, then [`MeshCells`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeshCells.html) will return the list in the form `{Line[{i, j}]..}`.

```
foo = DiscretizeRegion[Disk[], MaxCellMeasure -> 0.1];
bobbie = MeshCells[foo, 1][[All, 1]]
(*
 {{9, 10}, {10, 23}, {23, 9}, {35, 8}, {8, 9}, {9, 35}, {29, 20}, {20, 
  16}, {16, 29}, {6, 7}, {7, 20}, {20, 6}, {36, 12}, {12, 25}, {25, 
  36}, {23, 35}, {21, 7}, {7, 8}, {8, 21}, {20, 21}, {21, 16}, {29, 
  22}, {22, 5}, {5, 29}, {1, 27}, {27, 37}, {37, 1}, {24, 17}, {17, 
  23}, {23, 24}, {21, 35}, {35, 32}, {32, 21}, {19, 28}, {28, 
  31}, {31, 19}, {34, 15}, {15, 33}, {33, 34}, {3, 28}, {28, 2}, {2, 
  3}, {25, 26}, {26, 18}, {18, 25}, {24, 10}, {10, 11}, {11, 24}, {5, 
  6}, {6, 29}, {26, 13}, {13, 14}, {14, 26}, {31, 4}, {4, 22}, {22, 
  31}, {2, 27}, {1, 2}, {17, 33}, {33, 32}, {32, 17}, {15, 32}, {12, 
  13}, {13, 25}, {4, 5}, {30, 22}, {29, 30}, {30, 19}, {19, 22}, {17, 
  35}, {36, 11}, {11, 12}, {24, 36}, {36, 33}, {33, 24}, {18, 
  36}, {37, 14}, {14, 1}, {26, 37}, {37, 34}, {34, 26}, {28, 27}, {27,
   19}, {19, 37}, {3, 4}, {31, 3}, {16, 30}, {32, 30}, {16, 32}, {30, 
  15}, {15, 19}, {33, 18}, {18, 34}, {34, 19}}
*)
```

Check:

```
GraphicsRow[{
  foo,
  Show[
   foo,
   Graphics[
    GraphicsComplex[
     MeshCoordinates[foo],
     Line[bobbie]
     ]]
   ]}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: You beat me to it. +1

Comment: @RunnyKine  Haven't seen you much lately, it seems.  (Well since the end of June, I've been somewhat busy and not paying close attention.)  Good to hear from you in any case. :)

Comment: Thank you :). I've been busy with school work, so not much time to participate here.

Answer (score 0):

I was a bit confused about your definition of "connectivity" and which points are and are not to be selected, but I hope I understood what you wanted.

```
AllConnections=Table[DeleteCases[Flatten[Select[MeshCells[foo, 1][[All, 1]], #[[1]] == n || #[[2]] == n &]],n], {n, Length[MeshCells[foo, 0]]}];

FinalResult=Table[Partition[Flatten[{{i,AllConnections[[i,j]]},{ConstantArray[i,Length[Complement[AllConnections[[i]],Join[{AllConnections[[i,j]]},AllConnections[[AllConnections[[i,j]]]]]]]],Complement[AllConnections[[i]],Join[{AllConnections[[i,j]]},AllConnections[[AllConnections[[i,j]]]]]]}//Transpose}],2],{i,Length[AllConnections]},{j,Length[AllConnections[[i]]]}]
```

What this code does, after it has selected one point which is connected to starting point to select also all the others which are not connected to the first connected point. For example

```
GraphicsRow[Table[Show[foo = DiscretizeRegion[Disk[], MaxCellMeasure -> 0.1],ListPlot[Map[Part[MeshCoordinates[foo], #] &, FinalResult[[1, j]]],
 PlotStyle -> Blue, Joined -> True], ListPlot[Map[Part[MeshCoordinates[foo], #] &, FinalResult[[1, j]]][[1]], 
PlotStyle -> Red, Joined -> True]], {j, 4}]]
```

[image]

So, first you select red line (first connection) and look for all connections which are not neighbours (blue lines). I hope that this helps! Is this what you wanted?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it's not quite what I was looking for.  Essentially I've got a shape that's been discretized into triangles which has introduced lots of additional points.  I'm looking to create a list of the nodes that a each node is directly connected to.  I've edited the example in the original question a little to help make it clearer what I'm hoping to achieve.  Thanks for answering though.

Comment: Lets have a look at the example which is shown in my "answer". What would be result there? There are 4 points, lets called them (1,2,3,4) from bottom to top. Lets call the point of origin P (one to the most-right) What would be answer there? (P,1) and (P,4)... or?

Comment: Yes, if P is the point on the boundary that you've connected the lines too, and those points are 1-4, then the connectivity list would be {{p,1},{p,2},{p,3},{p,4}} if point p was indeed connected to all four points...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Guess Who It is and user21 for their help in the comments of the original question, if they want to submit the same answer fully I'll remove this no problems and vote theirs up.

Defining a region:

```
foo = DiscretizeRegion[Disk[], MaxCellMeasure -> 0.1]
```

Then the connectivity of the polygon data exists if the output of foo is inspected.  *(Guess Who It Is code)*

```
InputForm[foo]
```

The polygon component can be extracted using the following code. *(user21 code edited)*

```
test = ToString[InputForm[foo]];
jim = ToExpression[
  StringTake[
   test, {StringPosition[test, "Polygon"][[1, 1]], 
     StringPosition[test, "Properties"][[1, 1]] - 4}]]
```

Taking the first element from this leaves just the list data...

```
 jim=jim[[1]]
```

Gives a list that can now be parsed and tweaked to identify the connectivity.  I've sorted the list in the first line, but this step isn't strictly necessary...

```
moo = Sort[jim];
bob = Partition[Flatten[Riffle[moo, moo]], 2]
```

> {{1, 27}, {37, 1}, {27, 37}, {2, 27}, {1, 2}, {27, 1}, {3, 4}, {31, 
>     3}, {4, 31}, {3, 28}, {2, 3}, {28, 2}, {3, 31}, {28, 3}, {31, 
>     28}, {6, 7}, {20, 6}, {7, 20}, {8, 35}, {21, 8}, {35, 21}, {9, 
>     10}, {23, 9}, {10, 23}, {11, 36}, {24, 11}, {36, 24}, {12, 13}, {25,
>      12}, {13, 25}, {14, 37}, {26, 14}, {37, 26}, {16, 20}, {21, 
>     16}, {20, 21}, {17, 33}, {32, 17}, {33, 32}, {19, 15}, {34, 
>     19}, {15, 34}, {19, 28}, {31, 19}, {28, 31}, {19, 30}, {15, 
>     19}, {30, 15}, {19, 31}, {22, 19}, {31, 22}, {20, 29}, {6, 20}, {29,
>      6}, {21, 7}, {8, 21}, {7, 8}, {21, 20}, {7, 21}, {20, 7}, {21, 
>     32}, {16, 21}, {32, 16}, {21, 35}, {32, 21}, {35, 32}, {22, 4}, {5, 
>     22}, {4, 5}, {22, 30}, {19, 22}, {30, 19}, {23, 35}, {9, 23}, {35, 
>     9}, {24, 10}, {11, 24}, {10, 11}, {24, 17}, {23, 24}, {17, 23}, {24,
>      23}, {10, 24}, {23, 10}, {24, 33}, {17, 24}, {33, 17}, {24, 
>     36}, {33, 24}, {36, 33}, {25, 26}, {18, 25}, {26, 18}, {26, 
>     13}, {14, 26}, {13, 14}, {26, 25}, {13, 26}, {25, 13}, {26, 
>     34}, {18, 26}, {34, 18}, {26, 37}, {34, 26}, {37, 34}, {27, 
>     28}, {19, 27}, {28, 19}, {28, 27}, {2, 28}, {27, 2}, {29, 5}, {6, 
>     29}, {5, 6}, {29, 20}, {16, 29}, {20, 16}, {29, 22}, {5, 29}, {22, 
>     5}, {30, 22}, {29, 30}, {22, 29}, {30, 29}, {16, 30}, {29, 16}, {30,
>      32}, {15, 30}, {32, 15}, {31, 4}, {22, 31}, {4, 22}, {32, 30}, {16,
>      32}, {30, 16}, {32, 35}, {17, 32}, {35, 17}, {33, 15}, {32, 
>     33}, {15, 32}, {33, 36}, {18, 33}, {36, 18}, {34, 15}, {33, 
>     34}, {15, 33}, {34, 33}, {18, 34}, {33, 18}, {34, 37}, {19, 
>     34}, {37, 19}, {35, 8}, {9, 35}, {8, 9}, {35, 23}, {17, 35}, {23, 
>     17}, {36, 11}, {12, 36}, {11, 12}, {36, 12}, {25, 36}, {12, 
>     25}, {36, 25}, {18, 36}, {25, 18}, {37, 14}, {1, 37}, {14, 1}, {37, 
>     27}, {19, 37}, {27, 19}}

This shows that node 1 is connected to 27, 37 connected to 1, etc, etc...

Comment: Your result contains both `{a, b}` and `{b, a}` -- for example, `{1, 27}` and `{27, 1}`.  Is that what you want?  (My answer contains only one of the pairs, but the others are easily added.)

Comment: You're quite correct, my last needs some tidying up to remove duplicates